# Twitter Streaming API and Oauth for pulling hashtag

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth

I am trying to get Oauth to work with the Twitter Streaming API but I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error.  I found a blog that provided code for the Oauth authentication, but I had to tweak it to get it to compile.  Here's what I have so far in my main method:

```
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = null;
        StreamReader responseStream = null;

        String twitterUser = Properties.Settings.Default.TwitterAccount;
        String twitterPassword = Properties.Settings.Default.TwitterPassword;
        String twitterHashtags = Properties.Settings.Default.TwitterHashtags;

        String twitterConsumerKey = Properties.Settings.Default.TwitterConsumerKey;
        String twitterConsumerSecret = Properties.Settings.Default.TwitterConsumerSecret;
        String twitterAccessToken = Properties.Settings.Default.TwitterAccessTokens;
        String twitterAccessTokenSecret = Properties.Settings.Default.TwitterAccessTokenSecret;

        Int32 wait = 250;

        while (true) //Auto retry on error!
        {
            try
            {
                var postData = "track=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(twitterHashtags);
                var requestContentBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

                webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json"));
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.ContentLength = requestContentBuffer.Length;
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                webRequest.UserAgent = "OAuthTwitterStream";
                webRequest.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "deflate, gzip";
                webRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

                OAuthRequestAuthorizer _requestAuthorizer = new OAuthRequestAuthorizer(twitterConsumerKey, twitterConsumerSecret, twitterAccessToken, twitterAccessTokenSecret);

                _requestAuthorizer.Authorize(webRequest, postData);

                using (var dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(requestContentBuffer, 0, requestContentBuffer.Length);
                }

                webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

                while (true)
                {
                    string jsonText = responseStream.ReadLine();

                    dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText);

                    if (o.disconnect == null) //Sometimes you get a disconnect response, we don't want our clients to see this.
                    {
                        //do something with tweet object
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (WebException ee)
            {
                if (ee.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                {
                    if (wait < 10000)
                        wait = 10000;
                    else
                    {
                        if (wait < 240000)
                            wait = wait * 2;
                    }
                }

                Console.Error.WriteLine(ee.Message);

            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ee.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (webRequest != null)
                {
                    webRequest.Abort();
                }
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    responseStream.Close();
                    responseStream = null;
                }

                if (webResponse != null)
                {
                    webResponse.Close();
                    webResponse = null;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting: " + wait);
                Thread.Sleep(wait);
            }
        }
```

And here is the Oauth class:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace OAuth
{
    public class OAuthBase
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides a predefined set of algorithms that are supported officially by the protocol
        /// </summary>
        public enum SignatureTypes
        {
            HMACSHA1,
            PLAINTEXT,
            RSASHA1
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides an internal structure to sort the query parameter
        /// </summary>
        protected class QueryParameter
        {
            private string name = null;
            private string value = null;

            public QueryParameter(string name, string value)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.value = value;
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get { return name; }
            }

            public string Value
            {
                get { return value; }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Comparer class used to perform the sorting of the query parameters
        /// </summary>
        protected class QueryParameterComparer : IComparer<QueryParameter>
        {

            #region IComparer<QueryParameter> Members

            public int Compare(QueryParameter x, QueryParameter y)
            {
                if (x.Name == y.Name)
                {
                    return string.Compare(x.Value, y.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    return string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
                }
            }

            #endregion
        }

        protected const string OAuthVersion = "1.0";
        protected const string OAuthParameterPrefix = "oauth_";

        //
        // List of know and used oauth parameters' names
        //        
        protected const string OAuthConsumerKeyKey = "oauth_consumer_key";
        protected const string OAuthCallbackKey = "oauth_callback";
        protected const string OAuthVersionKey = "oauth_version";
        protected const string OAuthSignatureMethodKey = "oauth_signature_method";
        protected const string OAuthSignatureKey = "oauth_signature";
        protected const string OAuthTimestampKey = "oauth_timestamp";
        protected const string OAuthNonceKey = "oauth_nonce";
        protected const string OAuthTokenKey = "oauth_token";
        protected const string OAuthTokenSecretKey = "oauth_token_secret";

        protected const string HMACSHA1SignatureType = "HMAC-SHA1";
        protected const string PlainTextSignatureType = "PLAINTEXT";
        protected const string RSASHA1SignatureType = "RSA-SHA1";

        protected Random random = new Random();

        protected string unreservedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~";

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper function to compute a hash value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hashAlgorithm">The hashing algoirhtm used. If that algorithm needs some initialization, like HMAC and its derivatives, they should be initialized prior to passing it to this function</param>
        /// <param name="data">The data to hash</param>
        /// <returns>a Base64 string of the hash value</returns>
        private string ComputeHash(HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, string data)
        {
            if (hashAlgorithm == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("hashAlgorithm");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
            }

            byte[] dataBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            byte[] hashBytes = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(dataBuffer);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Internal function to cut out all non oauth query string parameters (all parameters not begining with "oauth_")
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameters">The query string part of the Url</param>
        /// <returns>A list of QueryParameter each containing the parameter name and value</returns>
        private List<QueryParameter> GetQueryParameters(string parameters)
        {
            if (parameters.StartsWith("?"))
            {
                parameters = parameters.Remove(0, 1);
            }

            List<QueryParameter> result = new List<QueryParameter>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters))
            {
                string[] p = parameters.Split('&');
                foreach (string s in p)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && !s.StartsWith(OAuthParameterPrefix))
                    {
                        if (s.IndexOf('=') > -1)
                        {
                            string[] temp = s.Split('=');
                            result.Add(new QueryParameter(temp[0], temp[1]));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result.Add(new QueryParameter(s, string.Empty));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is a different Url Encode implementation since the default .NET one outputs the percent encoding in lower case.
        /// While this is not a problem with the percent encoding spec, it is used in upper case throughout OAuth
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value to Url encode</param>
        /// <returns>Returns a Url encoded string</returns>
        protected string UrlEncode(string value)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char symbol in value)
            {
                if (unreservedChars.IndexOf(symbol) != -1)
                {
                    result.Append(symbol);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Append('%' + String.Format("{0:X2}", (int)symbol));
                }
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Normalizes the request parameters according to the spec
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameters">The list of parameters already sorted</param>
        /// <returns>a string representing the normalized parameters</returns>
        protected string NormalizeRequestParameters(IList<QueryParameter> parameters)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            QueryParameter p = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
            {
                p = parameters[i];
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", p.Name, p.Value);

                if (i < parameters.Count - 1)
                {
                    sb.Append("&");
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate the signature base that is used to produce the signature
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">The full url that needs to be signed including its non OAuth url parameters</param>
        /// <param name="consumerKey">The consumer key</param>        
        /// <param name="token">The token, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
        /// <param name="tokenSecret">The token secret, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
        /// <param name="httpMethod">The http method used. Must be a valid HTTP method verb (POST,GET,PUT, etc)</param>
        /// <param name="signatureType">The signature type. To use the default values use <see cref="OAuthBase.SignatureTypes">OAuthBase.SignatureTypes</see>.</param>
        /// <returns>The signature base</returns>
        public string GenerateSignatureBase(Uri url, string consumerKey, string token, string tokenSecret, string httpMethod, string timeStamp, string nonce, string signatureType, out string normalizedUrl, out string normalizedRequestParameters)
        {
            if (token == null)
            {
                token = string.Empty;
            }

            if (tokenSecret == null)
            {
                tokenSecret = string.Empty;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerKey))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("consumerKey");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpMethod))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("httpMethod");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(signatureType))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("signatureType");
            }

            normalizedUrl = null;
            normalizedRequestParameters = null;

            List<QueryParameter> parameters = GetQueryParameters(url.Query);
            parameters.Add(new QueryParameter(OAuthVersionKey, OAuthVersion));
            parameters.Add(new QueryParameter(OAuthNonceKey, nonce));
            parameters.Add(new QueryParameter(OAuthTimestampKey, timeStamp));
            parameters.Add(new QueryParameter(OAuthSignatureMethodKey, signatureType));
            parameters.Add(new QueryParameter(OAuthConsumerKeyKey, consumerKey));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                parameters.Add(new QueryParameter(OAuthTokenKey, token));
            }

            parameters.Sort(new QueryParameterComparer());

            normalizedUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}", url.Scheme, url.Host);
            if (!((url.Scheme == "http" && url.Port == 80) || (url.Scheme == "https" && url.Port == 443)))
            {
                normalizedUrl += ":" + url.Port;
            }
            normalizedUrl += url.AbsolutePath;
            normalizedRequestParameters = NormalizeRequestParameters(parameters);

            StringBuilder signatureBase = new StringBuilder();
            signatureBase.AppendFormat("{0}&", httpMethod.ToUpper());
            signatureBase.AppendFormat("{0}&", UrlEncode(normalizedUrl));
            signatureBase.AppendFormat("{0}", UrlEncode(normalizedRequestParameters));

            return signatureBase.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate the signature value based on the given signature base and hash algorithm
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="signatureBase">The signature based as produced by the GenerateSignatureBase method or by any other means</param>
        /// <param name="hash">The hash algorithm used to perform the hashing. If the hashing algorithm requires initialization or a key it should be set prior to calling this method</param>
        /// <returns>A base64 string of the hash value</returns>
        public string GenerateSignatureUsingHash(string signatureBase, HashAlgorithm hash)
        {
            return ComputeHash(hash, signatureBase);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a signature using the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm
        /// </summary>      
        /// <param name="url">The full url that needs to be signed including its non OAuth url parameters</param>
        /// <param name="consumerKey">The consumer key</param>
        /// <param name="consumerSecret">The consumer seceret</param>
        /// <param name="token">The token, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
        /// <param name="tokenSecret">The token secret, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
        /// <param name="httpMethod">The http method used. Must be a valid HTTP method verb (POST,GET,PUT, etc)</param>
        /// <returns>A base64 string of the hash value</returns>
        public string GenerateSignature(Uri url, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string token, string tokenSecret, string httpMethod, string timeStamp, string nonce, out string normalizedUrl, out string normalizedRequestParameters)
        {
            return GenerateSignature(url, consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, tokenSecret, httpMethod, timeStamp, nonce, SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a signature using the specified signatureType 
        /// </summary>      
        /// <param name="url">The full url that needs to be signed including its non OAuth url parameters</param>
        /// <param name="consumerKey">The consumer key</param>
        /// <param name="consumerSecret">The consumer seceret</param>
        /// <param name="token">The token, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
        /// <param name="tokenSecret">The token secret, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
        /// <param name="httpMethod">The http method used. Must be a valid HTTP method verb (POST,GET,PUT, etc)</param>
        /// <param name="signatureType">The type of signature to use</param>
        /// <returns>A base64 string of the hash value</returns>
        public string GenerateSignature(Uri url, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string token, string tokenSecret, string httpMethod, string timeStamp, string nonce, SignatureTypes signatureType, out string normalizedUrl, out string normalizedRequestParameters)
        {
            normalizedUrl = null;
            normalizedRequestParameters = null;

            switch (signatureType)
            {
                case SignatureTypes.PLAINTEXT:
                    return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Format("{0}&{1}", consumerSecret, tokenSecret));
                case SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1:
                    string signatureBase = GenerateSignatureBase(url, consumerKey, token, tokenSecret, httpMethod, timeStamp, nonce, HMACSHA1SignatureType, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);

                    HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1();
                    hmacsha1.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}&{1}", UrlEncode(consumerSecret), string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenSecret) ? "" : UrlEncode(tokenSecret)));

                    return GenerateSignatureUsingHash(signatureBase, hmacsha1);
                case SignatureTypes.RSASHA1:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Unknown signature type", "signatureType");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate the timestamp for the signature        
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual string GenerateTimeStamp()
        {
            // Default implementation of UNIX time of the current UTC time
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            return Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate a nonce
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual string GenerateNonce()
        {
            // Just a simple implementation of a random number between 123400 and 9999999
            return random.Next(123400, 9999999).ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

And finally the OAuthRequestAuthorizer class:

```
using OAuth;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

namespace LiveTwitter
{
    public interface IRequestAuthorizer
    {
        void Authorize(HttpWebRequest request, string postData);
    }

    public class OAuthRequestAuthorizer : OAuthBase, IRequestAuthorizer
    {
        private readonly string _twitterConsumerKey;
        private readonly string _twitterConsumerSecret;
        private readonly string _twitterAccessToken;
        private readonly string _twitterAccessTokenSecret;

        public OAuthRequestAuthorizer(string twitterConsumerKey, string twitterConsumerSecret, string twitterAccessToken, string twitterAccessTokenSecret)
        {
            _twitterConsumerKey = twitterConsumerKey;
            _twitterConsumerSecret = twitterConsumerSecret;
            _twitterAccessToken = twitterAccessToken;
            _twitterAccessTokenSecret = twitterAccessTokenSecret;
        }

        public override string GenerateNonce()
        {
            return new Nonce().Value;
        }

        private string BuildHeader(HttpWebRequest request, Uri uri)
        {
            var nonce = GenerateNonce();
            var timeStamp = GenerateTimeStamp();

            string normalizedUrl;
            string normalizedRequestParameters;

            var httpMethod = request.Method;
            var signature = GenerateSignature(uri, _twitterConsumerKey, _twitterConsumerSecret, _twitterAccessToken, _twitterAccessTokenSecret,
                                              httpMethod, timeStamp, nonce, out normalizedUrl,
                                              out normalizedRequestParameters);

            // https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request
            return
                string.Format(
                    "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{0}\", " +
                    "oauth_nonce=\"{1}\", " +
                    "oauth_signature=\"{2}\", " +
                    "oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", " +
                    "oauth_timestamp=\"{3}\", " +
                    "oauth_token=\"{4}\", " +
                    "oauth_version=\"1.0\"",

                    UrlEncode(_twitterConsumerKey),
                    UrlEncode(_twitterConsumerKey),
                    UrlEncode(nonce),
                    UrlEncode(signature),
                    UrlEncode(timeStamp),
                    UrlEncode(_twitterAccessToken));
        }

        public void Authorize(HttpWebRequest request, string postData)
        {
            //NOTE: It's a must to collect all param either in the header/querystring or post body
            var baseUri = string.IsNullOrEmpty(postData) || request.Method.ToUpper() == "GET"
                        ? request.RequestUri
                        : new Uri(string.Format("{0}?{1}", request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri, postData));

            request.Headers["Authorization"] = BuildHeader(request, baseUri);
        }
    }

    public class Nonce
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public Nonce()
        {
            Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the correct API keys and I think I have the correct settings set up on the application.  Any idea why I keep getting a 401?  Also, if there is a simpler way to do this by all means let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Temboo simplifies the OAuth process for Twitter by breaking it down into two calls:

- `InitializeOAuth` - returns a Twitter authorization URL that you can show to your users and have them grant your application access to their Twitter account
- `FinalizeOAuth`- returns the access tokens you need for authenticated access to the Twitter Streaming API.

You can experiment with Temboo's Twitter OAuth support in your browser from the link below and then generate the source code you need to use this behavior in your app. If your language isn't supported (Temboo does not current have a C# SDK), you can generate REST API cURL commands.

https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Twitter/OAuth/

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo, so let me know if you have any questions!)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably either found your bug or found another way of solving the problem by now, but in case you haven't, the 401 error is due to a copy paste error in your `OAuthRequestAuthorizer` class.  You submitted the first parameter twice in the string.format method in the BuildHeader function.

It now returns a 406 error when I try it, but at least its moved past your 401 problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue (and I think I might have taken the same code from the same blog looking at it).

I found that if I used all UPPER CASE characters for value of the track= parameter to the streaming API then I stopped getting the 401 errors.